# Marketing Cloud Journey Builder - The triggered send was paused but could not be published

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

we have a journey with the entry mode "Re-entry only after exiting". The source Data Extension is overwritten by automation weekly. On last run, we had about 4k subscribers in this DE and they exited the journey already (but subscribers remain in De till next overwrite).

We had some update on email contents, so we went to the journey and did the following:
select email > select Activity Summary > select different message > pick the email we just updated > Save.
Then we got the error message "Changes to the triggered send message were saved. The triggered send was paused but could not be published."

So I went to Email Studio > Interactions > Trigger Send > Journey Builder Send > select the journey.
I can see that the status is Paused.

My question is when I restart on Trigger Send, do the subscribers who are in DE receive the updated email? Our email update was for the next round and we do not want to send this email to those who already received the previous ver.

Any advice would be appreciated.
Thank you.

J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer lies in the way your journey is being triggered. Is the schedule of the journey is governed by the automation that overwrites the DE, then the contacts will not enter the journey, since they have been overwritten. However, if your journey runs on an independent schedule, and runs before the automation that is overwriting the DE, since they were exited and based on your re-entry criteria, the contacts will renter the journey again.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and the reason it happened is because the updated email template contained new dynamic text for the First Name of the subscriber. Basically the journey needs to have such content validated first before making it live. The best way to solve this is to launch a new version of the journey, update the email template, validate and then activate the new version of the journey.